# Etymology of "shark"

Tags: etymology, nouns

I found [Etymonline's entry](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=shark) on the word *shark* unusually inconclusive. Not only is the origin of the word uncertain, it is also not clear if *shark* was first applied to a dishonest person or to the sea creature.

It also had no mention of this positive connotation from *NOAD*:

> **2** an expert in a specified field : *a pool shark*.

Can any etymology sharks out there supply some of these missing links?

Comment: I'd always thought of the term Pool Shark to refer to someone who who hustles other people by pretending to be crap and tempting them to bet against him... I stand corrected...

Comment: @Omar: looking at the first uses of *pool shark* I find in Google Books, it seems that the original meaning was just anybody who regularly makes money by playing pool (so a predator at the pool table, which clearly involves a pun on the word pool), but not necessarily one who uses shady tactics. I have certainly heard it used with a negative connotation, though.

Comment: @Omar: Funny you should mention it. I had a debate with some friends about this and it was going to be my original question before I discovered the ambiguity of the word _shark_ itself. Interesting what @Peter found. Could still be worth its own question.

Answer (score 4):

["The Xoc, the Sharke, and the Sea Dogs: An Historical Encounter".](http://www.mesoweb.com/pari/publications/RT07/211-Xoc.html) 16Century from a Mayan word apparently.

But since sharks are fairly common in the North Atlantic and Mediterranean - I can't believe there wasn't an older term.

Comment: Finally got around to reading the article. Fascinating. I think it's a solid argument. The author addresses your doubts. I'd like to accept your answer, but feel it could be improved with a summary of the article and maybe a blockquote or two. I could edit it in if you'd like.

Comment: @Callithumpian, go ahead - I only read the intro

Answer (score 4):

*Carcharus* is Latin for dogfish, (deriving from Greek *carcharos* jagged: *Carcharodon*, the scientific name for the Great White family, means 'sharp tooth'),  so could be the origin. Also possible are Austrian German *Schirk*, sturgeon, or dialect French *cherquier* to seek, as well as German *schurke* scoundrel or Mayan *Xoc*. Finding all these in 10 minutes suggests to me that the true origin (whatever it is) is buried in a pile of plausible falsehoods.  (I evolved one of my own: could it be a mishearing of 'shagreen' [a leather made from skins of rays or sharks] as 'sharkskin'?  Sadly, *shagreen*, from *chagrin* untanned leather, seems to be younger than *shark*.)
It is suggestive, though, that the word came into English about the time that British sailors were first sailing to the Caribbean and South Atlantic, where sea sharks are found, while land sharks (lawyers, salvagemen, wreckers, etc) had been around for centuries.

Comment: Just finished reading the article linked to by @Martin. I recommend it. I'm sold on the Mayan _xoc_ theory.

Comment: I'm happy that the word comes from Hawkins (as in OED) but not at all convinced that *xoc* means shark rather than barracuda or 'sea monster'.

Answer (score 2):

The OED gives the following history:

> The word seems to have been introduced
>   by the sailors of Captain (afterwards
>   Sir John) Hawkins's expedition, who
>   brought home a specimen which was
>   exhibited in London in 1569. The
>   source from which they obtained the
>   word has not been ascertained. Cf.
>   Ger. dial. (Austrian) *schirk*
>   sturgeon

It disparages the idea that the noun came from the verb:

> The conjecture of Skeat that the name
>   of the fish is derived from shark v.1
>   is untenable; the earliest example of
>   the vb. is c 1596, and the passage
>   alludes to the fish

Comment: I think the Hawkins' men bit is key. Check out the link in @Martin's answer for a convincing blend of history and conjecture.

Answer (score 1):

Just heard that Shark in Arabic is called a Kirsh - in arabic it's the letters Q-R-Sh - reversed would give us Sh-R-Q - then came here to see if I was wrong. Just a hypothesis but maybe the origin is arabic

Comment: Any sources for your theory?